# box2d on separate thread

Tags: android, opengl-es, box2d

I am creating a box2d game on android.

- When I place world.step() in a separate thread from the opengl render thread and have the camera follow a body, the player jitters terribly.
- If I place world.step on the render thread before the draw commands, it renders perfectly even with camera following the body. But I cant use the extra power of multi-threading.

I am guessing this is a sync problem between threads? Any tips or source code examples?

Comment: When using a single thread, the world will step one time for every render. But when it's on another thread, it might step many times, or even zero times, between each render. Since it's rendering smoothly in a single thread, I would suggest that you only concern yourself with "the extra power of multi-threading" when you really have a problem that requires it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the physics engine on a separate thread you need to keep a copy of the state you need in the rendering thread (position, rotation for example) so you can render a consistent frame while the physics updates the bodies. Once the the physic's step is done, you synchronize both threads in order to copy the new positions/rotations. If your physics engine runs at a different rate than your rendering engine (120hz vs 60hz), you may want to copy the rendering data every two physics' frame.